# How do I know how many posters I have to stick to my enemies?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

So, I've been tasked with advertising for concerts. Great! I can do that. Problem is, I have to stick these posters to my enemies.

The [KoL wiki](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Advertise_for_the_Mysterious_Island_Arena) points out that

> The quest is completed once the total attack value of monsters you
>   have advertised on is at least 10,000. Adding +ML (via effects or
>   items) helps. The stronger the monsters you distribute posters to, the
>   fewer you'll need to hand out, but the stronger their retaliatory
>   strikes will be.

Alright, cool, I have a goal. Problem is, short of making sure I look up the attack value of each monster and add them all up by hand, I am not sure how I can keep track of this.

Is there something that tells me how close I am to completing this quest, sort of like the nuns' flavour text changing slightly as I got closer to bringing them back all the meat that the brigands stole?

Comment: FYI the best monster to stick this on is the [guy made of bees](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Guy_Made_Of_Bees), but you need ambidextrously funk-slung so you can also use the mirror to avoid being beaten up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep visiting the Arena while distributing the flyers you'll notice that the message the Hippy/Frat tells you changes with the amount of flyers you've distributed.

You can find the whole list of messages on the KoL wiki [quest page](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Advertise_for_the_Mysterious_Island_Arena#Text), but basically they keep praising you for your good work: once you get to the message that says that the arena is almost full it means you'll only have a few flyers left to distribute.

The best way to minimize your adventures spent doing the quest, especially if you're attempting a speedrun, is to save the bosses in the Pyramid and the Hole in the Sky, and possibly the monsters in the Junkyard, Orchard and Sonofa Beach (depending on the side you're on in the war). Using the Guy Made of Bees, while instantly completing the quest, is usually not worth it, since it takes too many adventures to set up. If you can afford to do that though it lets you avoid flyering around and enraging random monsters in the kingdom.